# How does the || operator work, and why wont in work in this if?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to learn the basics of JavaScript and just wanted to ask a quick question about the || operator. You see, I'm currently reading through w3school's guide to JavaScript and I saw that || was paired next to &&, which is an operator I have used and understood. w3schools described it as being equivalent to "or". Since I had used && as a way of expressing several conditions in an if, I thought || would be to express several acceptable results. After I added it in one of my scripts from before, it didn't work at all.

```html
<script>

function reply()
{
var answer = document.getElementById("questionPrompt").value;

if (answer == "Ok" || "ok") 
 {
    document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
    document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "";
 }
else {
    document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
    document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "";
     }
}
</script>

<input id="questionPrompt"></input>

<p id="rightResponse" style="color:green;"></p>

<p id="wrongResponse" style="color:red;"></p>

<button onclick="reply();">Ok?</button>
```

As you can see if you test it out, no matter what answer you give it the text is green when it is intended to be red if you get it wrong. I am not sure if my issue is at a misunderstanding of ||'s purpose or if it is the code instead. If it isnt the latter, please make an effort to make it as understandable as possible to a beginner like me, because after looking this up, I was left confused because of the terminology-heavy explanations.
Thank you!

Comment: You want `if (answer === "Ok" || answer === "ok")`. Stop using W3Schools (it's awful). The MDN is where it's at ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: Each condition  has to be resulted to a boolean.
In your `if (answer == "Ok" || "ok")` second condition is not a boolean.

Try `if (answer == "Ok" || answer == "ok") `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `answer == "Ok"` is being evaluated first, after which the result is compared to `"ok"`. Since `"ok"` is a truthy value itself, your comparison will always evaluate to `True` regardless of the input.

Try:
`if (answer == "Ok" || answer == "ok")`